# What mailbox features are required to 'Send an email from a shared mailbox' in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, email, flow, power-automate

I am preparing an I.T. request to create a *new* Shared Mailbox so that we can send automated emails via Power Automate, specifically using the [Send an email from a shared mailbox (V2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-from-a-shared-mailbox-(v2)) connector.

I want to make sure that I provide all necessary details in the request about the 'type' of shared mailbox that needs to be setup, as well as any necessary configuration details.

The reason I want to provide these details is that our *current* Shared Mailbox doesn't provide this functionality, I am not entirely sure why - details are pasted at the bottom of this post for context.

I.T. have already said they cannot *enable* this functionality on the *current* Shared Mailbox because it is out of their scope of support, however I have suggested that a *new* shared mailbox may have this functionality enabled by default, so they are happy to create a *new* shared mailbox if that is the case.

**Research**

There is some information here:

[Known Issues and Limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#known-issues-and-limitations)

which says:

> To use this integration, you will need access to an O365 mailbox that has the REST API enabled.

Are these the only requirements - ie that it is an `O365` mailbox with `REST API` enabled?

Is `REST API` enabled on new `O365 mailboxes` by default?

If not, is it a trivial process to enable this and where are the instructions?

**Question**

What mailbox features are required to 'send from Shared Mailbox' in Power Automate?

**Context**

*Our current Shared Mailbox 'Send an email from a shared mailbox (V2)' errors*

> REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox.
> This error can occur for sandbox (test) accounts or for accounts that are on a dedicated (on-premise) mail server.

*Possible Solutions*

Summary: Mailbox needs to be migrated
[REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox error for request to a mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/rest-api-is-not-yet-supported-for-this-mailbox-error)

Summary: Correct license needs to be added
[REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/REST-API-is-not-yet-supported-for-this-mailbox/td-p/3452)

Related reading:
[Issues with a Shared Mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#issues-with-a-shared-mailbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously configured Shared mailbox in Microsoft 365 admin center & sent an email using Power Automate successfully.

**Flow configuration**:

[image]

**Output Email**:

[image]

---

Follow below steps to create a new Shared mailbox & grant necessary permissions:

1. [Create a shared mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/create-a-shared-mailbox) from Microsoft 365 admin center or Exchange admin center
2. Grant below permissions to your user account:

   - Read and manage permissions: to use shared mailbox in 'Send an email from a shared mailbox' action
   - Send as permissions: to use shared mailbox in 'Send an email (V2)' action

**Read and manage permissions**:

[image]

**Send as permissions**:

[image]

---

**Note**: Permissions changes can take up to 60 minutes to take effect.

**Related reference**: [Send email from a common mailbox in Power Automate using Microsoft Teams email address or Shared Mailbox](https://ashiqf.com/2021/02/28/send-email-from-a-common-mailbox-in-power-automate-using-microsoft-team-or-shared-mailbox/)

Comment: So there was no specific step required to 'enable REST API' on the mailbox?  (There was no mention of it on the [Create a shared mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/create-a-shared-mailbox?view=o365-worldwide) or [Send email from a common mailbox in Power Automate using Microsoft Teams email address or Shared Mailbox](https://ashiqf.com/2021/02/28/send-email-from-a-common-mailbox-in-power-automate-using-microsoft-team-or-shared-mailbox/) links you shared)

Comment: Yes, while creating Shared Mailbox in Microsoft 365 (Office 365), I have not seen any 'Enable REST API' setting. Also, I have selected all apps (outlook, exchange web services, IMAP, etc.) in **Email apps** settings of shared mailbox (in M365 admin center).